# coffeescript default argument, when not passed, is not assigned to an outside variable with same name as arg

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Can anyone explain why this won't work? I am just running this off of the CoffeeScript page's "Try Coffeescript now" thing and my Chrome console logs the "nope" as you'll see below

```
x = true
foo = (x = x) ->
  console.log if x then "works" else "nope"
foo() # "nope"
```

If I had changed the x = true to y = true and ( x = x) to ( x = y ) in the argument definition

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seeing how the function is compiled makes the problem obvious:

```
  foo = function(x) {
    if (x == null) x = x;
    return console.log(x ? "works" : "nope");
  };
```

As you can see, if the `x` argument is null, `x` is assigned to it. So it's still null.

So, renaming the `x` variable to `y` fixes the problem:

```
y = true
foo = (x = y) ->
  console.log if x then "works" else "nope"
foo() # "nope"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually I think I learned more from knowing that I should check the compiled javascript now.

Answer (score 0):

arnaud's answer is correct. This approach also works:

```
x = true
do foo = (x) ->
  console.log if x then "works" else "nope"
```

The `do` syntax spares you from having to rename variables when capturing them in a function.

**Edit:** Actually, this code gives `"nope"` in the current version of CoffeeScript, though `do (x) ->` will give you `"works"`. See my comment below.

Comment: wow what a pleasure to have you here. Just got your book , as you may notice from the this question. (great book! Sadly, I have to wait for Node 0.6 to play with the 5x5. Am on win7 ) -- I just tried your code above in the "Try CoffeeScript" thing, but it's getting "nope".

Comment: @Nik Ack, sorry, my mistake—there's currently a bug (well, I'd call it one, at least) such that `do (x) ->` works but `do foo = (x) ->` doesn't. This, and some other `do` mishaps, are on record at [issue 960](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/960).

Comment: I see, I will follow that issue then, thanks for pointing it out and linking to it!